# HashMap returns null pointer for unknown reason

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

Hello good people of SO,

I'm having a hard time understanding why my code is returning a null pointer. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class GetTabByName {

    HashMap<String,JPanel> allTabs;

    public void getMap(HashMap<String,JPanel> allTabs){

        this.allTabs = allTabs;

             //this print works fine
        System.out.println(allTabs.get("addPatDocTab").getName());
    }

    public JPanel getTabByName(String tabName){

        JPanel tab = null;

            //this is where the problem occurs. even I try to print the line above
            //I get the same null pointer
        if(allTabs.containsKey(tabName)){
            tab = allTabs.get(tabName);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(tabName + " is not a tab");
        }
        return tab;
    } 
}
```

the error message is the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.GetTabByName.getTabByName(GetTabByName.java:23)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.AddEditElements.addElementsToPane(AddEditElements.java:14)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:177)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.SwingHome.createAndShowGUI(SwingHome.java:27)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.SwingHome.access$0(SwingHome.java:21)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.SwingHome$1.run(SwingHome.java:16)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

=====EDIT======

More relevant code:

```
//create a HashMap that connects the name of each tab to its corresponding JPanel
      //this map will be used for the method getTabByName
      HashMap<String,JPanel> tabsMap = new HashMap<String,JPanel>();
      for(Component tab:allTabs){

          JPanel tempTab = (JPanel)tab;
          tabsMap.put(tab.getName(), tempTab);
      }

      //pass the map to the GetTabsByName class so that other classes can access GetTabByName's getTabByName method
      GetTabByName passMap = new GetTabByName();
      passMap.getMap(tabsMap);

      AddEditElements subTab1 = new AddEditElements();
      subTab1.addElementsToPane();
```

and finally:

```
public class AddEditElements {

    //the method accepts a list of the tabs in Add/Edit
    public void addElementsToPane(){

        GetTabByName get = new GetTabByName();

        JPanel addPatDocTab = get.getTabByName("addPatDocTab");

        JRadioButton rdbtnPatient = new JRadioButton("Patient");
        rdbtnPatient.setBounds(0, 0, 109, 23);  

        addPatDocTab.add(rdbtnPatient); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are calling above methods?Can you show relevant code?

Comment: A debugger would be very helpful here. Something is passing in a null value, and a debugger allows you to look at the call stack for how it got there.

Comment: @anonymous I understand allTabs is null, the question is Why? I made the map accessible to the entire class, and the method getMap gets run before getTabByName. Dangling Piyush I will post more relevant code in a second

Comment: might be you are trying to refer Hashmap before it has got some values into it. check whether getMap() is getting called before method getTagByName().

Comment: @Shirish in my MainFrame() class I definitely have getMap() called before I call another class which calls getTagByName. I thought this was the problem originally but it doesn't seem to be so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void addElementsToPane() {
    GetTabByName get = new GetTabByName();
```

That's local to that method. `get` does not have anything to do with `passMap` (the one on which you invoked `getMap(tabsMap)`).

You probably want to pass `passMap` to `addElementsToPane()` method.

```
public class AddEditElements {

    public void addElementsToPane(GetTabByName passMap) { // add parameter       
        //GetTabByName get = new GetTabByName(); //don't create a new object
        JPanel addPatDocTab = passMap.getTabByName("addPatDocTab"); // <-------
```

That changes the signature of the method.

And then,

```
AddEditElements subTab1 = new AddEditElements();
subTab1.addElementsToPane(passMap); // pass the object with the populated map
```

Comment: negative, I pass the hashmap to the GetTabByName class to go to the getMap method. Maybe I'm not following you exactly, but this does not seem to be the issue

Comment: `new GetTabByName()` that creates a new object (instance) of the class `GetTabByName`. You should have only one object. Currently you are dealing with two different instances. You are setting the populated map in one instance and are trying to retrieve from the other.

Comment: you are a Guru indeed. thank you *very* much for your help. Can you please explain conceptually to me what happens when I do: subTab1.addElementsToPane(passMap) - since passMap is just an instance of GetTabByName, what exactly happens when I pass this to addElementsToPane?

Comment: `GetTabByName passMap = new GetTabByName();` That creates an object and assigns it to the variable `passMap`. Now when you pass it to your method like `subTab1.addElementsToPane(passMap)`, you are passing the reference to the object to your method, so that from within the method you can refer to that object. It basically needs some basic understand of how reference and objects work in Java, after some practice it will all be clear.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply, SO went down. Thanks for the explanation! Just to reiterate to make sure I understand: once I create the passMap object and use that to pass the Map, I need to use the same instance in the addElementsToPane class for the reference to hold true? Is that more or less true? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes SO went down for a while, I experienced it too. But, yes your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
GetTabByName get = new GetTabByName();
JPanel addPatDocTab = get.getTabByName("addPatDocTab");
```

If you follow what this does, it creates a new GetTabByName, which by default has a null allTabs. Then it calls get.getTabByName("addPatDocTab"); which tries to acces allTabs of that particular GetTabsByName.

You should assign something to allTabs before you call getTabByName.

In the class GetTabByName you could instantiate allTabs right away like this:

```
HashMap<String,JPanel> allTabs = new HashMap<String, JPanel>()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that because later I "return tab", and so it has to be initialized to something. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You could put the "return tab" in the if and in the else put return null or some sort of can_not_find_error.

Comment: Ah, you could just put the return statement in the if statement and remove "tab" all together as such:
`if(allTabs.containsKey(tabName)){
     return allTabs.get(tabName);
} else {
     System.out.println(tabName + " is not a tab");
     return null;
}`

Comment: sadly this is not the issue

Comment: I'm a big fan of constructors, I personally think this code would look nicer with a constructor that instantiates allTabs = to a new HashMap<String, JPanel>()

Comment: See your AddEditElements class. It creates a new GetTabByName. It sounds like you want to pass the one you already created. You could create a constructor in your AddEditElements class to accept an already made HasMap.

Comment: thanks again, if you see the answer I selected you'll note it's similar to what you are saying. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
getMap(HashMap<String,JPanel> allTabs) method
```

you are trying to assign the value to the globally defined

```
HashMap<String,JPanel> allTabs;
```

if my understaing id right.

so try the following 
make the

```
HashMap<String,JPanel> allTabs global variable name differntly
```

like

```
HashMap<String,JPanel> globalAllTabs;
```

and try the same

Before that make sure by printing the globally defined hashmap inside

```
getTabByName(String tabName) method
```

Comment: I tried changing the name of the global hashmap, and it works in the first method (getMap), but again same issue once its run in the second :/